# ¿A qué se debe que el array se crea con valores nulos y no con su tipo de dato por defecto en Java?

Tags: java, array

## El problema

Se supone que en Java al crear un array, éste se llenaría con sus tipos de dato por defecto. Es decir, si es un array de booleanos, éste tendría booleanos `false` si no se asigna ningún valor a sus elementos. Si es un array de enteros, éste tendría elementos con valor `0`...

Estaba probando estos fragmentos de código en Java, en la *1ª forma* me llena los array con valores `null`, no con valores por defecto según el tipo.

#### 1ª forma: Código con ¿booleanos?

Llena el array con nulos

```
    System.out.println("\n\n¿Boolean?:");
    Boolean arrNoBol[] = new Boolean[7];
    for (Boolean bolActual : arrNoBol)
        System.out.print(bolActual + " ");
```

#### *Resultado:*

```
¿Boolean?:
null null null null null null null
```

#### 2ª forma: Código con booleanos

Llena el array con verdaderos booleanos (que son falsos)

```
    System.out.println("\n\nBoolean:");
    boolean arrSiBol[] = new boolean[7];
    for (boolean bolActual : arrSiBol)
        System.out.print(bolActual + " ");
```

#### *Resultado:*

```
Boolean:
false false false false false false false
```

Lo mismo ocurre con enteros.

#### 1ª forma: Código con ¿enteros?

Llena el array con nulos.

```
   System.out.println("\n\n¿Int?:");
    Integer[] arrNoInts = new Integer[7];          
    for (Integer intActual : arrNoInts)
        System.out.print(intActual + " ");
```

#### *Resultado:*

```
¿Int?:
null null null null null null null
```

#### 2ª forma: Código con enteros

Aquí crea los valores enteros:

```
    System.out.println("\n\nInt:");
    int[] arrSiInts = new int[7];          
    for (Integer intActual : arrSiInts)
        System.out.print(intActual + " ");
```

#### *Resultado:*

```
Int:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

## La pregunta

¿Por qué al escribir el código de la primera forma los arrays se crean con valores nulos por defecto y no con valores según el tipo?

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas, cuando creas los array como has hecho, se ve que asigna valor null a cada elemento del array. Supongo que reservará memoria dependiendo del tipo de dato que sea el array.

Comment: No, no asigno nada a los array. Precisamente, deberían llenarse con los valores por defecto según el tipo de dato, como ocurre en la _2ª forma_. La duda es por qué en la _1ª forma_ se asignan valores nulos y no los valores por defecto: `false` para booleanos y `0` para enteros.

Comment: No lo había entendido, perdona. En el primer caso o primera forma, no estás rellenando el array con un tipo de dato booleano o entero, lo estás rellenando con un objeto de tipo Bool o Integer, es como si hicieses un array de personas, mientras no hagas el new vas a tener el objeto como null.

Comment: Precisamente, por ahí andaba la cuestión @PabloSimonDiEstefano. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Por qué al escribir el código de la primera forma los arrays se crean
>   con valores nulos por defecto y no con valores según el tipo?

Respuesta corta: En Java los objetos son null por defecto porque se especificó así.

En Java, al declarar un array de un tamaño distinto de cero, todos los elementos se rellenan con su valor por defecto:

- Los tipos primitivos se rellenan con `0` (`int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char`, `short`, `byte`) o `false` (que es el equivalente en el tipo `boolean`)
- Los objetos (o mejor dicho, los punteros a objetos) apuntan a null, que es el equivalente a no apuntar a nada.

El segundo caso aplica a todo lo que extienda a `Object`, incluyendo los "wrappers" de los tipos primitivos (`Integer`, `Char`, `Short`...) y a la clase `String`, por ejemplo.

Si lo que buscas es una respuesta a "¿Por qué se decidió así?" tendrías que preguntar a los que diseñaron Java, pero parece algo lógico: ¿Para qué reservar memoria y llamar al constructor de un objeto si no sabemos qué uso se le quiere dar? Es el programador el que elige qué hacer con su array.

También conviene recordar que lo mismo se aplica a los atributos de un objeto: al instanciarlo, si el constructor no asigna valor a algún atributo, éste valdrá 0 si es un tipo primitivo o `null` si es un objeto.

Pero esto no aplica a las variables de un método, con lo que puedes tener un error de compilación si intentas usar una variable a la que no se le ha dado explícitamente un valor anteriormente.

Comment: Quedó bastante claro, muchas gracias.

Comment: Una diferencia importante: un tipo primitivo **siempre** tiene un valor, porque ya define la posición de memoria que se usará. Java define unos valores por defecto, pero por ejemplo en C se permite que sencillamente se "inicialice" con el valor que había en esa posición de memoria (es decir, cualquier posible valor). La inicialización a `null` de referencias a objetos es lo más acorde a POO pero, como no se puede aplicar a primitivas, había que optar por valores por defecto o estilo C (y a Java no le gustan las cosas indefinidas).

Answer (score 1):

En java, tienes dos tipos de datos:

**Tipos primitivos**

`int`, `boolean`, `long`, `char`, `double`, etc, son tipos de datos primitivos, es decir una variable que simplemente almacena un valor en memoria, pero que no dispone de ningun metodo/funcionalidad para trabajar con ellos.

**Tipos de envoltura**

`Integer`, `Boolean`, `Long`, `Character`, `Double`, son objetos de envoltura sobre los datos primitivos, básicamente "potencian" los tipos de datos primitivos, aportándoles métodos y distintas funcionalidades.

Por eso en tu ejemplo, al rellenar tipos de datos primitivos, se coge el valor por defecto a 0, y al hacerlo con objetos de envoltura, se te ponen valores null, que es como no apuntar a nada. Ya que los tipos de datos primitivos nunca pueden tener valor null.

Answer (score 0):

De la primera forma (Boolean) estás declarando un object que por defecto tiene el valor null si no inicializas. 
De la segunda forma (boolean) estás declarando un tipo primitivo que por defecto tienen el valor false.

La cuestión se encuentra en el tipo de variable que quieres usar. Revisa los tipos y sus diferencias.

Un saludo.