# Como funcionan los arrays de tipo objeto?

Tags: java, array

Quiero saber como funciona realmente un arrays de objetos... o de clase? No se bien como llamarlo realmente, he buscado libros y videos y solo se limitan a enseñar como se usa pero no enseñan cómo funciona. He probado usando el modo debug del IDE pero aun asi no me queda del todo claro. Aca un ejemplo:

Clase Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Biblioteca[] array = new Biblioteca[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new Biblioteca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce libro n°" + (i + 1)));
    }
    for (Biblioteca i : array) {
        System.out.println(i.getLibro());
    }
}
```

Clase Biblioteca:

```
public class Biblioteca {

  private String libro;

  public Biblioteca(String NombreLibro) {

    libro = NombreLibro;

  }

  public String getLibro() {
    return libro;
  }
}
```

También quisiera saber por qué tengo que poner "new Biblioteca" cada vez que introduzco un dato en el array.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Un array de objetos es simplemente una coleccion con varios objetos. Cada elemento del array (se accede por posicion) es un objeto en tu ejemplo Biblioteca. Tienes que usar new Biblioteca para añadir un dato en el array porque el array es de tipo Biblioteca.

Comment: Usa arraylist es mas comodo de usar que un array normal que requiere detallar un tamñao y es mas engorro de usar

Comment: Pregunta relacionada (no duplicada): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103049/a-qu%c3%a9-se-debe-que-el-array-se-crea-con-valores-nulos-y-no-con-su-tipo-de-dato-p

Comment: He eliminado el primer párrafo de la pregunta porque es totalmente innecesario. Aunque en un primer momento hacer las preguntas *impersonales* pueda hacer parecer la página más *arisca*, cuando alguien visita preguntas de otras personas se agradece ir directamente al asunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Quiero saber como funciona realmente un arrays de objetos?

Empecemos analizando esta sentencia:

```
Biblioteca[] array = new Biblioteca[3];
```

Esa simple línea hace tres cosas:

- Crea un objeto de tipo `Biblioteca[]` y guarda la dirección base (del primer elemento) del objeto en el puntero implícito `array` (digo `implícito` porqué en Java no existen los punteros, pero internamente si).
- Luego de haber creado el objeto, el constructor pasa a ejecutarse y se le envía el tamaño del arreglo (en este caso `3`).
- Por último, durante la ejecución del constructor, se crea el arreglo de objetos (que en realidad es un arreglo de punteros) y se guarda en un puntero implícito la dirección base del arreglo.

Para que lo entiendas mejor, imagina que el objeto de tipo `Biblioteca[]` fue insertado en memoria de esta forma:

```
A:
|0x8|    
|0x12|  -> B:  |0x20|  |0x24|    |0x28|
               (null)  (null)    (null)

Pointer array: 0x8
```

El bloque `A` representa el objeto creado (básicamente es el que hace referencia el puntero `array`). En nuestro ejemplo he puesto que la dirección `0x8` (el puntero `array` apunta hacia esa dirección) es la dirección base del objeto.

Luego tenemos la dirección `0x12`, esa dirección de memoria en realidad es la de un puntero. Ese puntero hará referencia a la dirección base del bloque `B`, debo recalcar que el bloque `B` en realidad es el arreglo de objetos o mejor dicho el `arreglo de punteros`.

**¿Por qué un arreglo de objetos es un arreglo de punteros?**

La respuesta es sencilla, porqué lo que guardamos en el bloque `B` son las direcciones bases de cada objeto, que posteriormente crearemos, por defecto esas 3 direcciones (`0x20`, `0x24`, `0x28`) tendrán un valor `null`.

Ahora, analicemos las siguientes sentencias:

```
//Biblioteca[] a = new Biblioteca[5]; --> esta ya la analizamos.
a[0] = new Biblioteca("Matematica");
a[1] = new Biblioteca("Fisica");
a[2] = new Biblioteca("Quimica");
```

Pero antes de comenzar el análisis, aquí podemos contestar a tu segunda duda:

> > También quisiera saber por qué tengo que poner "new Biblioteca" cada vez que introduzco un dato en el array.

**¿Qué pasaría si `a[0]` no le asignamos una referencia de un objeto válido?**

La respuesta es sencilla, la instrucción `a[0]` por defecto tendrá un valor `null` y si llegaras hacer esto:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Biblioteca[] a = new Biblioteca[5];
        System.out.println(a[0].getLibro());//error
    }
}
```

Te dará la excepción [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) y esto se debe porqué estás intentando de acceder a una dirección de memoria que al programa no le pertenece. Así que por esa razón, es necesario crear el objeto con la palabra clave `new`.

Ahora, volvamos con el análisis del anterior código. Al momento de escribir estas tres sentencias:

```
a[0] = new Biblioteca("Matematica");
a[1] = new Biblioteca("Fisica");
a[2] = new Biblioteca("Quimica");
```

Estaríamos creando 3 objetos y posteriormente, se le estaría asignando la dirección base del objeto a cada puntero del `arreglo de punteros`.

Actualicemos nuestro mapita de memoria:

```
A:
|0x8|    
|0x12|  -> B:  |0x20|  |0x24|    |0x28|
               (0x40)  (0x60)    (0x70)

C:
|0x40|

D:
|0x60|

E:
|0x70|

Pointer array: 0x8
```

El bloque `C`, `D`, `E` representa cada objeto creado de tipo `Biblioteca`. En este caso, solo he puesto una dirección de memoria al objeto porqué en tu clase `Biblioteca` solo tienes un atributo, pero si tuvieras más, las direcciones del bloque `C`, `D`, `E` aumentarían.

Ahora, centrémonos en el bloque `B`, habíamos hablado que las direcciones `0x20`, `0x24`, `0x28` son las direcciones de memoria de cada puntero del arreglo de objetos; sin embargo, el contenido de cada puntero cambiará, debido a que, hemos creado los 3 objetos de  tipo `Biblioteca`.

Si te das cuenta, para poder entender como funcionan los arreglos de objetos, necesitas saber dos conceptos básicos:

- [Punteros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica))
- [Array of Pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm)

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 4):

Está bien que sea "Array de Objetos" porque el array se llena en tiempo de ejecución, que es cuando existen los objetos.
Qué es lo que quieres saber realmente?

```
Biblioteca[] array = new Biblioteca[3];
```

En ese momento se guarda en memoria el espacio necesario para guardar 3 registros que indican en qué lugar del heap se encuentra el objeto. Todavía no hay objetos.

Una instancia de clase (es decir "un objeto") se crea en algún momento, ese momento es cuando se hace un `new`:

```
Biblioteca variableBiblioteca = new Biblioteca("algun String")
```

En ese momento se crea un objeto del tipo `Biblioteca` en algún lugar de la memoria (ese lugar destinado a objetos se le dice "heap") con su respectiva dirección. La variable `variableBiblioteca`lo que verdaderamente contiene es la dirección dónde se encuentra el objeto dentro del heap.

```
array[i] = variableBiblioteca;
```

En una asignación de ese estilo, lo que pasa de fondo es que en el registro `i` se va a guardar la dirección de memoria dónde se encuentra el objeto que se le asignó (el mismo valor que esta guardado en la variable, es decir, se copia ese valor)

Sin crear la variable, como lo hiciste tu, funciona de la misma manera.

Answer (score 2):

Genial que aprendas de forma autodidacta te dejo unos comentarios en tu codigo que espero te permitan entender como funcionan los arreglos:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Biblioteca[] --> es la instancia de el arreglo de objetos
            // array --> nombre de la variable que va a manejar el arreglo
            // =new Bibliotecas --> crea una instancia en memoria de el arreglo de objetos 
            // NOTA(siempre que manejes objetos para crear un espacio en memoria tienes que usar el NEW para  crear un nuevo espacio de memoria).
            // [3] --> espacio en memoria que ocupa el arreglo de objetos 
            Biblioteca[] array = new Biblioteca[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                // array --> nombre de la variable de arreglo de objeto para referencia el arreglo
                //[i]  --> es la posicion que del arreglo de objetos (o el espacio de memoria) al que se le esta asignando un valor
                // =new Biblioteca.... -->  crea instancia de el objeto Biblioteca que sera almacenado en el arreglo de objetos
                array[i] = new Biblioteca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce libro n°" + (i + 1)));
            }
            for (Biblioteca i : array) {
                System.out.println(i.getLibro());
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora una de tus dudas es por que el **new** tienes que entender como funciona un **objeto**,te explico como funciona y con los **comentarios del codigo** y las **referencias que estan al final** ya puedes sacar tus concluciones o investigar un poco mas, cuando usas objetos siempre manejas las siguiente **estructura**, **"(1) Objeto (2) nombre = (3) new (4) Objeto();"**,  y cada uno de estos componentes tiene un rol asi:

1. es la referencia o instancia al objeto que quieras usar
2. Es el nombre que deseas usar para usar dicho objeto dentro de este espacio de trabajo o clase
3. reservas un nuevo espacio en memoria para dicho objeto (en el caso actual lo usas para un arreglo de objetos y lo pide por los arreglos son objetos que pertenecen a los lenguajes)
4. es la referencia al constructor de dicho objeto  para crear la instancia inicial el mismo.

pero te dejare algunas referencias que ami juicio explican bien algunos conceptos que deberia adquirir en caso de que aun no los sepas:

1. [clases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSUvGPB6oE8)
2. [Objetos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTkryyqMHNI)
3. [Constructores](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQfMR6ZIRgc)
4. [Arreglos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7Lv6Zdr63I)

Ahora como consejo personal, trata de aprender primero la logica se que queremos "*programar*"a la loca y ver resultado pero primero aprender la teoria o porlomenos mezcla lo uno con lo otro.

**Nota**: para mi la teoria me ha salvado de todo tipo de problemas y dudas asi que aconsejo la ames, la leas, te la comas y la uses por que si quieres programar es tu vida y mas como autodidacta.

-->[Documentacion de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), como veo que trabajas java te dejo la documentacion de java.

suerte....