# Problemas con un Array como Atributo - JAVA

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo una clase llamada UsuarioDonatario que hereda algunos atributos de la clase padre Usuario. El problema que tengo es a la hora de ingresar datos en un atributo que es un array llamado ProgramaDonacion[] en la clase UsuarioDonatario. El usuario debe poder agregar programas de donacion en este arreglo, y esto se hace mediante el metodo agregarPrograma. Pero al tratar de ingresar los datos, simplemente no se guardan en el arreglo. Adjunto codigo:

Clase Usuario

```
package proyectofinal;

public class Usuario {

    //Atributos
    private String telefono;
    private String correo;
    private String clave;

    //Constructor
    public Usuario(String telefono, String correo, String clave) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

}
```

Clase UsuarioDonatario

```
package proyectofinal;

public class UsuarioDonatario extends Usuario {

    //Atributos
    private String nombreInstitucion;
    private String ruc;
    private String direccion;
    private ProgramaDonacion[] programaDonacion = new ProgramaDonacion[10];

    //Constructor
    public UsuarioDonatario(String nombreInstitucion, String ruc, String direccion, String telefono, String correo, String clave) {
        super(telefono, correo, clave);
        this.nombreInstitucion = nombreInstitucion;
        this.ruc = ruc;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setNombreInstitucion(String nombreInstitucion) {
        this.nombreInstitucion = nombreInstitucion;
    }

    public void setRuc(String ruc) {
        this.ruc = ruc;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public void setProgramaDonacion(ProgramaDonacion[] programaDonacion) {
        this.programaDonacion = programaDonacion;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombreInstitucion() {
        return nombreInstitucion;
    }

    public String getRuc() {
        return ruc;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public ProgramaDonacion[] getProgramaDonacion() {
        return programaDonacion;
    }

    //Metodos
    public void visualizarInfoInstitucional() {
        System.out.println("Institucion: " + nombreInstitucion);
        System.out.println("RUC: " + ruc);
        System.out.println("Direccio: " + direccion);
        System.out.println("Telefono: " + super.getTelefono());
        System.out.println("Correo: " + super.getCorreo());
        System.out.println("Clave: " + super.getClave());
    }
    
    public void agregarPrograma(String nombrePrograma){
        int i = buscarPrograma();
        
        if(i != -1){
            programaDonacion[i].setNombrePrograma(nombrePrograma);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ya no se pueden crear mas programas!");
        }
    }
    
    //Metodos Auxiliares
    public int buscarPrograma(){
        int i;
        
        for(i = 0; i < programaDonacion.length; i++){
            if(programaDonacion[i] == null){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Clase ProgramaDonacion

```
package proyectofinal;

public class ProgramaDonacion {

    //Atributos
    private String nombrePrograma;
    private TipoDonacion tipoDonacion;
    private UsuarioDonatario usuarioDonatario;
    private DonacionEfectivo[] donacionesEfectivo;
    private DonacionProductos[] donacionesProductos;

    //Constructor
    public ProgramaDonacion(String nombrePrograma, TipoDonacion tipoDonacion) {
        this.nombrePrograma = nombrePrograma;
        this.tipoDonacion = tipoDonacion;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setNombrePrograma(String nombrePrograma) {
        this.nombrePrograma = nombrePrograma;
    }

    public void setTipoDonacion(TipoDonacion tipoDonacion) {
        this.tipoDonacion = tipoDonacion;
    }

    public void setUsuarioDonatario(UsuarioDonatario usuarioDonatario) {
        this.usuarioDonatario = usuarioDonatario;
    }

    public void setDonacionesEfectivo(DonacionEfectivo[] donacionesEfectivo) {
        this.donacionesEfectivo = donacionesEfectivo;
    }

    public void setDonacionesProductos(DonacionProductos[] donacionesProductos) {
        this.donacionesProductos = donacionesProductos;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getNombrePrograma() {
        return nombrePrograma;
    }

    public TipoDonacion getTipoDonacion() {
        return tipoDonacion;
    }

    public UsuarioDonatario getUsuarioDonatario() {
        return usuarioDonatario;
    }

    public DonacionEfectivo[] getDonacionesEfectivo() {
        return donacionesEfectivo;
    }

    public DonacionProductos[] getDonacionesProductos() {
        return donacionesProductos;
    }

}
```

Clase Principal (main)

```
package proyectofinal;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables Compartidas
        String telefono, correo = null, clave = null;
        //Variables Donante
        String nombreDonador, apellidoDonador, cedula;
        //Variables Donatario
        String nombreInstitucion, ruc, direccion;

        //Variables Auxiliares
        int aux1 = 0, i = 0, iDonante = 0, iDonatario = 0;
        //Inicializacion de los objetos
        UsuarioDonante donantes[] = new UsuarioDonante[100];
        UsuarioDonatario donatarios[] = new UsuarioDonatario[100];
        //QUEMADO DE DATOS
        
        //UsuarioDonatario
        donatarios[0] = new UsuarioDonatario("Institucion1", "1234567890123", "Lugar1", "0987654321", "institucion1@gmail.com", "4444");
        

        //Menu de Opciones
        do {
            System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION-----");
            //System.out.println("1. Ingresar Sesion como Donante");
            **System.out.println("2. Ingresar Sesion como Donatario");**
            System.out.println("3. Salir");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");

            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
                sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION COMO DONANTE-----");

                    //Ingreso del Correo
                    sc.nextLine();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su correo electronico: ");
                        correo = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Ingreso de la Clave
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su clave: ");
                        clave = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Verificacion de los datos para iniciar sesion
                    for (i = 0; i < donantes.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            if (correo.equals(donantes[i].getCorreo()) && clave.equals(donantes[i].getClave())) {
                                System.out.println("Inicio de Sesion Exitoso!");
                                inicioSesionDonante(donantes, i);
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                            System.out.println("No se pudo iniciar sesion. Verificar los datos ingresados!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----INICIO DE SESION COMO DONATARIO-----");

                    //Ingreso del Correo
                    sc.nextLine();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su correo electronico: ");
                        correo = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Ingreso de la Clave
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese su clave: ");
                        clave = sc.nextLine();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                        sc.nextLine();
                    }

                    //Verificacion de los datos para iniciar sesion
                    for (i = 0; i < donatarios.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            if (correo.equals(donatarios[i].getCorreo()) && clave.equals(donatarios[i].getClave())) {
                                System.out.println("Inicio de Sesion Exitoso!");
                                inicioSesionDonatario(donatarios, i);
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                            System.out.println("No se pudo iniciar sesion. Verificar los datos ingresados!");
                            sc.nextLine();

                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR!");
                            sc.nextLine();
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ha salido de la aplicacion exitosamente");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;

            }

        } while (aux1 != 3);

    }

    public static void inicioSesionDonante(UsuarioDonante[] donante, int i) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables
        int aux1 = 0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido " + donante[i].getNombre() + " " + donante[i].getApellido() + "!\n");

        do {
            //Menu de opciones del donante
            System.out.println("-----MENU DE OPCIONES-----");
            System.out.println("1. Visualizar Informacion Personal: ");
            System.out.println("2. ");
            System.out.println("3. ");
            System.out.println("4. ");
            System.out.println("5. Cerrar Sesion");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");

            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }

            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----VISUALIZAR INFORMACION PERSONAL-----");
                    donante[i].visualizarInfoPersonal();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Ha cerrado sesion con exito!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;

            }
        } while (aux1 != 5);

    }

    **public static void inicioSesionDonatario(UsuarioDonatario[] donatario, int i) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables ProgramaDonacion
        String nombrePrograma;
        //Variables
        int aux1 = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Bienvenido!\n");
        do {
            //Menu de opciones del donatario
            System.out.println("-----MENU DE OPCIONES-----");
            System.out.println("1. Visualizar Informacion Institucional: ");
            System.out.println("2. Agregar Programa de Donaciones");
            System.out.println("3. ");
            System.out.println("4. ");
            System.out.println("5. Cerrar Sesion");
            System.out.println("Ingresar una de las opciones: ");
            try {
                aux1 = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Ingresar solo valores numericos!");
                sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            switch (aux1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----VISUALIZAR INFORMACION INSTITUCIONAL-----");
                    donatario[i].visualizarInfoInstitucional();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----AGREGAR PROGRAMA DE DONACIONES-----");
                    nombrePrograma = "Programa1";
                    donatario[i].agregarPrograma(nombrePrograma);
                         
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Ha cerrado sesion con exito!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar una opcion valida!");
                    break;
            }
        } while (aux1 != 5);
    }**

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En Java, al declarar un array de un tamaño distinto de cero, todos los elementos se rellenan con su valor por defecto:

Los tipos primitivos se rellenan con 0 (int, long, float, double, char, short, byte) o false (que es el equivalente en el tipo boolean)

Los objetos (o mejor dicho, los punteros a objetos) apuntan a null, que es el equivalente a no apuntar a nada.

[seguir leyendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103049/a-qu%C3%A9-se-debe-que-el-array-se-crea-con-valores-nulos-y-no-con-su-tipo-de-dato-p)

Bien al declarar tu Array

```
ProgramaDonacion[] programaDonacion = new ProgramaDonacion[10];
```

estas rellenando de null esos campos,por lo cual no puedes hacer uso del set,por lo antes mencionado

> Si a un objeto no inicializado (referencia null) se le trata de aplicar un método o se intenta hacerlo intervenir en un proceso que requiere un objeto inicializado, se obtiene una excepción tipo “NullPointerException”

```
programaDonacion[i].setNombrePrograma(nombrePrograma);//error
```

lo que debes hacer es crear un objeto de la clase ProgramaDonacion a través del parámetro `nombrePrograma`

```
 public void agregarPrograma(String nombrePrograma){
        int i = buscarPrograma();
        
        if(i != -1){
            programaDonacion[i]=new ProgramaDonacion(nombrePrograma);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ya no se pueden crear mas programas!");
        }
    }
```